# What is this symbol used in Kabaneri of the Iron Fortress?

Tags: koutetsujou-no-kabaneri

While watching *Kabaneri of the Iron Fortress*, I saw this symbol during the opening song:

[image: symbol painted on the Iron Fortress]

But what exactly does this symbol stand for? Is it ever mentioned what this stands for? Have I missed something? I also think I saw it once in the first episode, painted on the train, so I'm guessing it is the symbol for the train itself, but I'm not sure... I just want to know for what is this symbol used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this post](http://kabaneri.com/special/rokon/) on the official website, this is the 浄化マーク, meaning "purification mark". It is derived from / inspired by [older variants of the character 六](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%85%AD#Glyph_origin), which is the "Rok-" in the phrase "Rokkon Shōjō" and means "six". This symbol is written on things to indicate that the things in question are "pure" (free of *kabane*, presumably).

I don't recall this being mentioned in the anime.